# Delete and Undelete upvoted answer point does not get added

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, deleted-answers

Recently I deleted my upvoted answer on stackoverflow. My reputation got down by 10 points as expected.
After that I undeleted the answer again, it shows upvoted but reputation didn't increased.
why so?

Comment: Your [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2539103/undefined-variable?tab=reputation) shows a +10 associated with that answer 55 minutes ago. Maybe some kind of caching issue...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks it might be caching issue. Because it is now reflecting in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be patient, your reputation will be restored in due course.

When deleting or undeleting posts, the effect on your reputation is not instant. A batch process recalculates your reputation after a little while (in the next hour or so).